# Checkpoint in Declarative Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cloudbees, checkpointing

I am looking at [Cloudbees documentation](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/index.html#workflow-sect-checkpoint) that says :

> The correct approach is to always keep the checkpoint step outside of any node block, not associated with either an agent or a workspace

The sample example given is for a scripted pipeline. I tried to implement this in Declarative Pipeline, but keep getting error. The only way I can make it work is :

```
stage ('Promotion Checkpoint') {
    steps {
        checkpoint 'Ready for Manual intervention'
        timeout(time: 60, unit: 'SECONDS') {
            input message: 'Do you want to proceed?'
        }
    }
}
```

My understanding is a stage in Declarative pipeline is similar to node in Scripted pipeline. I cannot make checkpoint work outside of stage or step, which seems to be my interpretation of suggestion from Cloudbees. Can someone help with right usage outside of checkpoint?

Comment: The above results in :
    Using checkpoint inside of node {} is unsupported and unreliable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your are facing a problem of declarative pipelines which make things which should run outside of agent and workspace kinda confusing.

The "normal" declarative pipeline has a agent defined at the top

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage("Build") {
      echo 'Build' 
    }
  }
}
```

But now all stage tags will use the same agent and workspace. This makes it easier to write "standard" pipelines but making it impossible to have a command not using any agent. So using `checkpoint`or writing a pipeline not blocking an executor when using `input` becomes impossible.

So the suggested right way for declarative pipeline is to use `agent none` at the top level pipeline and specify the `agent any` or `agent none` in each `stage`.

There are two examples in the [CloudBees documentation](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/index.html#workflow-sect-checkpoint-files). You can also find such workarounds for `input` in Jenkins documentation.

So one solution using the agent switch would look like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage("Build") {
      agent any
      steps {
        echo "Building"
      }
    }
    stage("Checkpoint") {
      agent none //running outside of any node or workspace
      steps {
        checkpoint 'Completed Build'
      }
    }
    stage("Deploy") {
      agent any
      steps {
        sh 'Deploying'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is also one with uses a `node` block in a declarative pipeline.

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages{
    stage("Build"){
      // no agent defined will be solved with node
      steps{
        node('') { // this is equivalent to 'agent any'
          echo "Building"
        }
        checkpoint "Build Done"
      }
    }
    stage("Deploy") {
      agent any
      steps {
        echo 'Deploy'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the explanation and link really helped.
I would think that inability to set agent globally and override it in a stage to none is a bug, but that is a topic for another day